# Excel VBA - search a website's html for a character and return a title

Tags: html, vba, excel

I'm trying to scrape data from a website that may have structured their data a bit irregular

the html of interest is

```
<a href='https://website.com/id=2021'>SampleText 
<img src='https://website.com/img/sample.jpg'   
class='tinyflag'></a>
<br />SampleName 
</td>
<td style='text-align:center;'>
    01/01/2015 <span style='color: #FFFF00;' 
     title='Active in last 24 hours'>&#9670;</span>
```

what i want to do is search for the character (string?) "&#9670" which displays as a diamond on the webpage and return the title for it. in this example, it would be the text 'Active in the last 24 hours'

I am doing this in excel and can navigate to the correct pages but i cannot figure out how to reference the title or &#9670 to return the desired text

Comment: More details - *exactly how* are you doing this scraping? Are you using IE or XMLHTTP ?  Some of your existing code would help.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the sample data in A1 cell, you can use the following code, to replace unwanted parts:

```
Range("A1").Replace "*title=", "", xlPart
Range("A1").Replace ">&#9670*", "", xlPart
```

If you want to extract the title and leave the original data unchanged:

```
Dim iStart As Integer, iEnd As Integer
Dim title As String

iStart = InStr(1, Range("a1").Value2, "title=") + 6 '6-length of the pattern
iEnd = InStr(1, Range("a1").Value2, ">&#9670")

title = Mid(Range("a1").Value2, iStart, iEnd - iStart)
```

There's only one sample row, so it's hard to judge if it will work in every case.

Comment: sorry i should have specified - i am wanting to do this all with VBA and not load or copy/paste source code. the desired outcome is excel will navigate  (with ie.visible = false) to the desired page, identify and scrape the text and return only the relevant bits. there are many pages i have to do this to which can be easily done with a loop, if i have to do it one by one it defeats the purpose a bit. thanks!

Comment: @kamelkid2 you do not have to do it one by one, I assume you have the whole line in some variable, so you should be able to adapt the second code by replacing `Range("a1").Value2` with the name of your variable

Comment: this is what i am struggling with - i cannot seem to reference this entire line. i can reference the link itself by Set elems = .getElementsByTagName("a")
            For Each e In elems 
but cant figure out the syntax/logic to capture the rest

Comment: @kamelkid2 Your question is a bit misleading, I thought you already have the line you posted and you just want to extract a part of it. Now I'm a bit lost where the real problem is... I think it's going to be hard to solve it without some sample code.